# Can i use pickerview in my iphone application using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

#### Duplicate:

> [How can i use picker view in iphone application using cocos2d ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614004/how-can-i-use-picker-view-in-iphone-application-using-cocos2d)

Hello everyone i am working on iphone gaming project.In this game i want spin some image (like reel spin).But i can not do this.Can i use picker view in this application using cocos2d.If can then give some instruction how can i do that or any different solution for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything your want. I am constantly amused by the number of people who think that Cocos2d is some sort of world that you enter where you cannot bring any of your old friends. Cocos2d is just a library that makes OpenGL easy for games, and that is all it is. All it is.

I think you might benefit from trying a few easier projects first. I have made the mistake of trying to jump into something beyond my understanding, and while in the end it may have been beneficial, I sometimes wish I had learned in a more systematic manner.